# Extract value from Cluster<PersonMyStuff> in google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am trying the cluster library given by Google on my Map. The clustering is happening properly but I am trying to extract the value from cluster. I am not sure how to go about doing it?

The cluster size is 2. I am always getting the first value.

```
@Override
public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<PersonMyStuff> cluster) 
{
    String firstName = cluster.getItems().iterator().next().name;

    Log.i("MyMaps","Cluster Size" +cluster.getSize());
    Log.i("MyMaps","First Name" +firstName);

    return true;
}
```

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only accessing the first element by calling `next` on the iterator once.   Try looping through all the elements in the collect.

```
@Override
public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<PersonMyStuff> cluster) 
{
    Collection<PersonMyStuff> items = cluster.getItems();
    Log.i("MyMaps","Cluster Size" +cluster.getSize());
    for(PersonMyStuff item : items) {
        Log.i("MyMaps","First Name" + item.name);
    }

    return true;
}
```